# How to partition data based on variable timestamp records - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have a SQL database like so:

```
Id    Text       DateTime
----------------------------
1     Event1     1/1/1900 12:00:00
2     Event2     1/1/1900 12:10:11
3     Event3     1/1/1900 12:11:10
4     Event2     1/1/1900 12:12:12
5     Event3     1/1/1900 12:13:19
6     Event1     1/1/1900 12:14:22
7     Event2     1/1/1900 12:15:15
8     Event2     1/1/1900 12:18:16
9     Event3     1/1/1900 12:23:00
10    Event3     1/1/1900 12:24:11
```

I want to find which of the events happen first, partitioned by Event1 occurence. i.e. Which event2s happen before any other event2, but AFTER event1.

So far I have something like:

```
SELECT t1.* from Database t1 join
(select ROW_NUMBER() OVER
(PARTITION BY Text ORDER BY DateTime ASC) AS Ranking,
Id from Database
where  DateTime>(select MAX(DateTime) from Database where Text = 'Event1')) t2
on t1.id=t2.id and t2.Ranking=1
```

This only works for the last events though (because I'm using MAX). Is there some clever way to do this that I just can't see?

EDIT:
Clarification, I'd like all events (including event1 or not, doesn't matter) to be flagged if they are the first of their type to occur after event1 has happened.

In this case, the output would look like:

```
Id
---
2
3
7
9
```

or

```
Id
---
1
2
3
6
7
9
```

Comment: Can you add sample output to your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am making some modification to your Row_Number(). I am setting it to
>   new partiton Id for my logic. Please excuse. Here am going to create a Partition
>   for each Event1,2,3 next Event1,2,3 etc etc with the use of Cursor,
>   since there are no other possibility to take the Partition.

```
 DECLARE @ROW INT=0,
        @TEXT VARCHAR(10),
        @DATETIME DATETIME,
        @TMPDATE DATETIME,
        @CUR CURSOR

        SET @CUR = CURSOR FOR SELECT #TABLE.Text [Text],#TABLE.[DateTime] FROM #TABLE
                   ORDER BY [DateTime]

        OPEN @CUR           
            FETCH NEXT FROM @CUR INTO @TEXT,@DATETIME
            WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
            BEGIN   

                IF(@TEXT='Event1')
                BEGIN

                    SET @ROW=@ROW+1;

                END

                UPDATE #TABLE SET ID=@ROW WHERE [Text]=@TEXT AND [DateTime]=@DATETIME;  

                FETCH NEXT FROM @CUR INTO @TEXT,@DATETIME       
            END

        CLOSE @CUR
        DEALLOCATE @CUR
```

> Now am going to Partition accoring to the Id and Text to get the
>   Minimum Datetime

```
        SELECT DISTINCT ID,[TEXT]
        ,CASE WHEN [TEXT]= 'EVENT1' THEN [DateTime] ELSE MIND END [DATETIME]        
        FROM
        (
            SELECT ID,[Text],[DateTime]
            ,MIN([DATETIME]) OVER(PARTITION BY ID,[Text]) MIND
            FROM #TABLE 
        )TAB
        ORDER BY [DATETIME]
```

Answer (score 0):

If the first `Event2` is always preceded by `Event1` you can use:

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DateTime) RN
             FROM Table1)
SELECT b.*
FROM cte a
JOIN cte b
 ON a.text = 'event1' and b.text = 'event2'
 AND a.RN = b.RN - 1
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7f0d6/6/0)